# Jruby, What popular ruby gems use C under the hood?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jruby

From what I understand, to use Jruby you basically convert the project to a .jar and deploy to tomcat etc.

But you can't use any gems that are written in c correct?

Which popular gems use c under the hood that I should look out for?

Any other incompatibilities?

Answer (score 1):

> But you can't use any gems that are
>   written in c correct?

Yet, but JRuby 1.6 (currently in RC1) adds experimental support for C extensions.

> Which popular gems use c under the
>   hood that I should look out for?

Several Gems have JAVA alternatives or native implementation, such as Nokogiri.
Which Gem really depends on your project: God, Bcrypt-Ruby, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- [BlueCloth](http://deveiate.org/projects/BlueCloth) is a reasonably-popular gem that is written in C.
- The [pg](http://rubygems.org/gems/pg) gem providing native PostgreSQL support is also rather popular.